# Взлом через код страницы

Tags: javascript

Для некоторых AJAX-запросов на странице используются data-атрибуты, записанные в теги кнопок, вызывающих эти запросы. Например, для реализации возможности добавлять репутацию пользователю на сайте, кнопка "Мне нравится" выглядит следующим образом:

`<span class = "CLASS" data-like = "1">Мне нравится</span>`

То есть, атрибут `data-like` отвечает за то, сколько баллов репутации будет добавлено пользователю, создавшему материал. Пользователи различных групп видят разные кнопки, вследствие чего могут совершенно по-разному влиять на эту репутацию.

При вызове AJAX-запроса просто берется значение `data-like` и передается в PHP-скрипт. Проблема в том, что, поменяв значение атрибута в коде страницы, пользователь может добавить себе любое количество репутации.

Как обычно решаются подобные задачи?

Comment: Считайте, что пользователь знает весь ваш API и планируйте его соответственно.

Answer (score 2):

Очень просто - все поступающие на сервер данные (не важно, от пользователя или стороннего API), должны проверятся на допустимость.

В данном случае, надо проверять, достаточно ли у пользователя возможностей для выполнения данного действия.

Answer (score 1):

Обычно такие задачи лучше и правильно решать на серверной стороне.

Сценарий следующий:

- Данные вроде data-like = "XXX" создаются и хранятся на сервере, на клиент обычно не передаются или передаются исключительно в информативных целях.
- На стороне клиента происходит событие.
- Отправляем AJAX-запрос только с теми данными на которые должен влиять пользователь.
- При обработке запроса на сервере используем ранее сохраненное значение data-like.

Comment: Ну, допустим, параметры типа `data-like` я унесу в PHP-скрипт, вызываемый через AJAX. Так? Но на сайте много разных кнопок, в том числе, среди них есть и кнопки бана пользователя администратором, реализуемые через такой же механизм.

То есть, получается, что кнопка в коде страницы, все же, должна иметь какой-то параметр `data-type`, отвечающий за ее тип, даже если все остальные будут перемещены в PHP-скрипт. Заменив этот параметр с `like` на `ban`, например, пользователь сможет забанить другого пользователя.

А если этого параметра нет - как скрипт узнает, какие действия ему выполнять?

Comment: Серверная сторона обязана контролировать возможность осуществлять действия каждым пользователем. Вам стоит ознакомиться с [Access Control List](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACL). Даже если пользователь подменит данные, а он это обязательно сделает, или угадает супер секретный запрос на сервер - сервер все равно не допустит выполнение функционала, который не разрешен этому пользователю.

Comment: Есть еще некоторая проблема. Будучи связанным некоторыми ограничениями в той системе, которую использую, некоторые вопросы решаю обходными путями. Один из таких путей - сохраненный в коде шаблона `div` с данными о текущем пользователе - ID, имя и некоторые другие данные. К этому объекту обращаюсь из JavaScript для получения, например, ID пользователя - очень важной информации в некоторых случаях. Эти же данные отправляются и на сервер. Вроде, не я один так поступаю, и других путей решения этой проблемы пока не вижу.

Comment: То есть, я могу перенести на сервер все дополнительные данные типа количества баллов за нажатие на кнопку "Мне нравится" и даже ID текущего пользователя, немного потрудившись, я могу узнать на сервере. Но есть данные, которые там так просто не узнаешь - например, ID материала, которому ставится отметка "Мне нравится" - эти данные должны передаваться на сервер со стороны...